# R Shiny tabPanel does not automatically got to top of page when clicked

Tags: r, shiny

Using

```
ui <- navbarPage("mytitle",
           position = "fixed-top",
           tabPanel("tab1", "long pieces of text..."),
           tabPanel("tab2", "long pieces of text..."))
```

and each of your tabs are long enough to require scrolling. How do you make it so that when you click on the `tabs` on the navbar you switch tabs but also go back up to the top of the page and not just where you were position on the previous page?

I imagine it might require some javascript intervening but can't figure how.

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**
Here's a real working example

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
                 title = "TITLE",
                 position = "fixed-top",
                 inverse = TRUE,
                 id = "inTabset",
                 collapsible = TRUE,
                 tabPanel("Tab1", 
                          h1("long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
                             ")),
                 tabPanel("Tab2", 
                          h1("long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
                          long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
                             "))

                 )

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: please provide full working example

Comment: the tabPanels are at the top of the page, so you would have to be already at the top when you want to click them? What am i missing here,...?

Comment: Not if you include the argument `position = "fixed-top"` into navbarPage. This will make the navbar stay at the top of your screen even when you scroll to the bottom of the page

Comment: hmm ruins the ui for me, looking forward to your full working example,..

Comment: included an example, looking forward to your solution. Thx ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added a simple js code so so that when you switch tabs you go back to the top of the page.

The js code that is added is the following, which tells you to scroll to the top of the page when click event is observed for the tab.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#inTabset a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').bind('click', function (e) {
               $(document).load().scrollTop(0);
               });
               
               });
```

In your code it would look something like this:

```
 library(shiny)
 
 ui <- navbarPage(
   title = "TITLE",
   position = "fixed-top",
   inverse = TRUE,
   id = "inTabset",
   collapsible = TRUE,
   tabPanel("Tab1", 
            h1("long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
               long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
               ")),
   tabPanel("Tab2", 
            h1("long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
               long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,long pieces of text,
               ")),
   tags$script(" $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#inTabset a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').bind('click', function (e) {
               $(document).load().scrollTop(0);
               });
               
               });")
   
            )
 
 server <- function(input, output, session){}
 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

**[EDIT]:**
Looks, like after shiny new version release the above js code stopped working. Replacing the above js code with the following code should work:

```
  tags$script(" $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#inTabset a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').on('click', function (e) {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
               });

               });")
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this solution to work, @SBIsta. I wonder if anything has changed over the past few years?

Comment: @Matt Cowgill, I have edited the answer for the latest version.

Comment: @Graham I have edited the answer for the latest version.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks very much, @SBista.

Comment: @SBista, How could this be adapted to have the same functionality upon clicking an ```actionButton``` that  performs ```updateTabsetPanel``` to open a new tab? Thanks

Comment: @Graham If your button id in `actionButton` is `myid`, then the script would be `tags$script(" $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#myid').on('click', function (e) {
          window.scrollTo(0, 0)
               });

               });")`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @SBista your Shiny + JS skills are incredible!